# Rsync/scp to Remote Host which requires RSA token

Tags: linux, jenkins, rsa, rsync, scp

I use Jenkins to run a shell script, which copies JAR files to remote host after build is successful
Remote host is now protected using 2FA and I cannot copy jars
On Jenkins, now I see this on console output

```
 +-----------------------------------------+
 | Please use RSA SecurID token to log in. |
 +-----------------------------------------+
```

I can manually copy using my RSA Hard Token
I can always change my script to use SCP insted of RSYNC if this is possible to automate using SCP

How to automate this scenario ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible by using a RSA token. An RSA token would require that someone has to sit in front of the build every time (that might be possible, but not feasible).   Why not using a separate, really restricted account that can f.e. only upload files?